# How can I inject interface into controller's constructor in Yii2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, interface, yii2

I would like to inject interface `app\models\IFoo`

```
private $foo;

public function __construct($id, $module, IFoo $foo, array $config = [])
{
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    $this->foo = $foo;
}
```

How should I set container to correct resolving the dependency in concrete class `app\models\Foo` which implements `IFoo`?

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of this? Might be easier to answer.

Comment: I've implemented IFoo in two concrete classes: Foo and FooStub. I would like to use stub for testing and so on. And I want inject interface into controller and set concrete class in setup file (web.php or other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call it like that in entry script:

```
\Yii::$container->set('app\models\IFoo', $concreteClass);
```

where `$concreteClass` is either `'app\models\Foo'` or `'app\models\FooStub'`.

Comment: I guess you can add it in web.php for non-test env and in test.php for test env.